# Calculate $\frac{1+i\tan \alpha}{1 - i \tan \alpha}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have been asked to calculate $\frac{1+i \tan \alpha}{1-i \tan \alpha}$, where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

So, I multiplied top and bottom by the complex conjugate of the denominator:

$\frac{(1+i \tan \alpha)(1+ i \tan \alpha)}{(1-i \tan \alpha)(1+ i \tan \alpha) } = \frac{1 + 2 i \tan \alpha + i^{2} \tan^{2} \alpha}{1-i^{2} \tan^{2} \alpha} = \frac{1 + 2i \tan \alpha - \tan ^{2} \alpha}{1 + \tan^{2} \alpha} = \frac{(1-\tan ^{2} \alpha)+2 i \tan \alpha}{\sec ^{2} \alpha} =\displaystyle \frac{1-\tan^{2} \alpha }{\sec ^{2} \alpha} + 2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha i$

Is this all that there is to do? Have I simplified it enough?

Comment: Perhaps each of your coefficients can be simiplified?

Comment: it is $\exp(2i\alpha)=\cos 2\alpha+i\sin2\alpha$.

Comment: First, $\frac{(1-\tan^2\alpha)}{\sec^2\alpha}=\cos^2\alpha -\sin^2\alpha=\cos 2\alpha$. Second, $i 2 \sin\alpha\cos\alpha=i \sin 2 \alpha$. So the final expression is $\cos 2\alpha + i \sin 2 \alpha$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll continue from where you left to get a simpler form :

- The real part :

$$\frac{1-\tan \alpha^2}{1+ \tan \alpha^2}=\frac{\cos^2 \alpha-\sin^2 \alpha}{\sin^2 \alpha+ \cos^2 \alpha}=\cos2\alpha$$

- The imaginary part :

$$2\sin \alpha \cos \alpha=\sin 2\alpha$$

A simpler form is thus :

$$\frac{1+i\tan \alpha}{1-i \tan \alpha}=\cos2 \alpha+i \sin2\alpha$$

Answer (score 6):

Well what you really should've tried is multiplying the numerator and denominator by $\cos \alpha$ which would give you,
 $$\frac{\cos\alpha +i \sin \alpha}{\cos\alpha -i \sin \alpha}=\frac{e^{i\alpha}}{e^{-i \alpha}}=e^{i 2 \alpha} = \cos 2\alpha + i \sin 2\alpha$$

Comment: @shaswta, thank you for this incredibly helpful solution. I don't know why I didn't see that myself.